# unique constraints in Oracle. How does it work?

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

I just added a new column `manager_id` to an existing table with a `unique constraint`.   I used this syntax to populate the `manager_id` column:

```
update employees
set manager_id = &id
where job_id = '& job';
```

When I run this code I get an error message:

> ORA-00001: unique constraint (HR.MAN_UK) violated

This column is empty so how is it possible for me to violate a constraint?

Comment: How many rows will match the condition `where job_id = &id` ?

Comment: for the first one i tried , just one row, but there are some that will return more than one row

Answer (score 0):

You can violate the constraint if `employees` has multiple rows that match `job_id = '& id'`.  That is, you are setting multiple rows to the same id in the statement.

The conflicts are not with existing values.  They are in the set of values you are setting in the `update`.

Comment: U are right,  i just checked  and i discovered the job_id entry had more than one output .

Answer (score 0):

> "for the first one i tried , just one row"

That seems unlikely,  Oracle only throws a unique constraint violation when we try to populate a constrained column with a second identical.  So if the MANAGER_ID column is empty before you run the update the JOB_ID must be hitting more than one row.

> "there are some that will return more than one row"

If the business logic is that a manager can manage more than one person - at let's face it that's the norm - then there should not be a unique constraint on Manager ID.  So drop it.

What you should have is a foreign key, either referencing the EMPLOYEES primary (a manager must be an employee) or, if you have one, the MANAGERS table (a manager must be a manager).